helm convert -f values.yaml gitlab/gitlab Error: error unmarshaling JSON: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type string
helm convert -f values.yaml gitlab/gitlab
Error: error unmarshaling JSON: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type string
it worked once but now it is not converting anything, the values.yaml file is correct, i even tried to use the suggested command from the help but got the same error
helm convert --set persistence.enabled=true stable/mongodb

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
